# memory leak issue in Backbonejs App

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, memory-leaks, requirejs

I'm using `Backbonejs` and `Requirejs` for creating a single page web app.
It seems like my app has `memory leaks`.

For testing I've created a sample code. It creates a view object, call its `render` function and attach the returned `html` into the `DOM`.
The returned `html` has a `button`. After clicking the button, its `callback` calls `destroy` function where the view is destroyed.

However, when I run `chrome heap profilier`, I can see `detached DOM tree` still hanging around. Looking deep into it, one can see `references` kept by `jQuery`.

I have doubt whether this is memory leakage or not.
If yes mycode is not keeping any references.
So does the problem lies in `jQuery` ?

Here's is [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32577704/MyTest.zip) to sample code.
I've also attached screen shots of heap snapshots.

[image: Heap snapshot 1]

[image: Heap snapshot 2]

[image: References for Detached DOM element]

Comment: As a general advice: when dealing with this kind of problems, try to isolate each elements: get rid of requirejs so that you have piece less to handle while debugging. Another advice is to upgrade to Backbone 1.0.0 and make use of the new `listenTo` and `stopListening` functions, that have been introduced exactely to deal with this kinds of problems. Keep in mind that calling `remove`  on a View will also call `stopListening`.

Comment: @gustavohenke backbone doesn't have any issues with memory leaks. they are created by developers :)

Comment: If you have memory problems start reviewing the location of all your handlers ... possibly might be some handlers getting set implicitly by your view that remove doesn't handle.

Comment: @amchang87 please look at the third image, you will notice that backbone is not keeping any reference,its jQuery.

Comment: @namero999 I'm not listening to any model's events,I'm simply attaching some html in the DOM.My leakage concern is not model right now but the detached DOM tree which is consuming a large part of memeory in my original app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications built using backbone often have memory leaks caused by orphaned views. I deal with this by using marionette which manages my views for me. Using backbone directly isn't a typical approach, as it's really a toolkit upon which frameworks are developed.

Comment: Actually, Backbone is fine for use directly without additional frameworks and indeed is used directly by a huge number of developers. However your point regarding orphaned views is valid. Managing the cleanup of orphaned views should be standard process of any backbone implementation.

Comment: I don't actually agree with backbone being 'fine' for direct use. I'm pretty experienced in all aspects of software development, and I've used backbone myself for the last year. I breathed a sigh of relief when I moved to Marionette, and I deleted half my code. I would always recommend Marionette over direct backbone.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I've used Marionette. It did awesome job for me but in this case I'm also cleaning up my views so the fact that view's being orphaned is less.Right now my biggest concern is leaking DOM tree.If you see last image you will notice jQuery is keeping some references.I request you to please go through my code, its very simple and it shows my concern.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I guess I should have said: many people choose to manage memory leaks using Backbone directly, which is entirely possible and many choose to use a framework which does it for them. At the end of the day, the framework is doing the same thing under the hood. Either choice is valid and it comes down to personal preference and yes, frameworks that do it for you may save a lot of time :)

Answer (score 1):

go through this links u will get more idea and you may find possible solution to your problem

https://paydirtapp.com/blog/backbone-in-practice-memory-management-and-event-bindings/

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/03/19/backbone-js-and-javascript-garbage-collection/

best of luck 
I hope you solve this problem quickly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please summarise the links in your answer; that way, if they go stale the answer won't be completely useless.